# How to apply AutoNumeric to all selectors?

Tags: javascript

**class: float**

With this example, AutoNumeric applied only to the first element input with class the `float`.

```html
    <script src = "https://unpkg.com/autonumeric" ></script>
    
    <form>   
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="26" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(26).Answer" />
    <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="27" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(27).Answer" /> 
     <br /> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="28" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(28).Answer" /> 
     <br /> 
     
    
    <script>
      const autoNumericOptions = {
        allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
        decimalCharacter: ",",
        digitGroupSeparator: "",
        //emptyInputBehavior: "zero",
        watchExternalChanges: true
      };
    new AutoNumeric(".float", autoNumericOptions); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Autonumeric.multiple to apply it to multiple elements at once.

```html
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/autonumeric" ></script>
    
    <form>   
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="26" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(26).Answer" />
    <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="27" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(27).Answer" /> 
     <br /> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="28" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(28).Answer" /> 
     <br /> 
     
    
    <script>
      const autoNumericOptions = {
        allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
        decimalCharacter: ",",
        digitGroupSeparator: "",
        //emptyInputBehavior: "zero",
        watchExternalChanges: true
      };
    AutoNumeric.multiple(".float",null, autoNumericOptions); 
    </script>
```